Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim
I have a Java Springboot application throwing SQL Error and it's driving me nuts:
2024-05-29 07:49:14.446  WARN 53856 --- [nio-8080-exec-]o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001
2024-05-29 07:49:14.446 ERROR 53856 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Transaction (Process ID 174) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
Could not unwrap this [org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl@16273c34] as requested Java type [org.hibernate.procedure.ProcedureOutputs]

The strange thing is, I do NOT get the error when connecting to the DEV SQL server. But when I connect to TST, I see these errors all the time and the application bombs on various REST calls.
Only the database connection is changing. The code is EXACTLY the same. And it throws this error in random places, almost all of which are just stored proc calls to get data.
I've truncated the tables on the TST database and tried entering new records, but the problem persists.
I'm at a loss.

Transactions are deadlocking. You didn't help us to determine you problem because you posted a question which doesn't have any useful information to analyse. This is a possible answer to your question which you probably  have to answer yourself. If it was helpful then don't forget to upvote it.
